# How to Delete Files and Application Data Container Values in One Go?

Tags: c#, windows-8, local-storage, storagefile

I have a reset function in my app which brings the app back to default state. There for I need to remove the four files I created and remove the settings I created in the `ApplicationDataContainer`.
This is how I remove the files

```
try
{
    StorageFile file = await localfolder.GetFileAsync("HistoryFile");
    if (file != null)
    {
        await file.DeleteAsync();
    }
}
catch
{
    //Catch Process
}
```

Is there a function which removes all the files together? When I tried the following code

```
localfolder.DeleteAsync()
```

It removed the LocalState folder along with the files, I jus need to remove the files not the folder.

And is there anyway in which I jus can remove all the values stored in ApplicationDatacontainer in one go? rather than removing them one by one like this?

```
localSettings.DeleteContainer("exampleContainer");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove application data from its local data store, try this.

```
await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.ClearAsync(
     Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataLocality.Local);
```